# Parsing sales force query payload

Tags: mule, mule-component, mule-el

I am querying some data from Salesforce using a Mule flow after subscribing to one of the Push Topic. After the data is queried, I can see the payload using #[message.payload.next()] but when I am trying to retrieve 'StageName' field using these expressions : 'payload[0].StageName' message.payload.StageName payload['StageName'] it's not working. I can see in the log it's printed values that is a Map but retrieving the field is not working.

payload[0].StageName - this works fine in Mule 3.3.2 environment but not working in my Mule 3.7.3, appreciate if any of you could help.

Answer (score 0):

The data returned after Salesforce query is of type `ConsumerIterator`. Just use a `set payload` with value `#[org.apache.commons.collections.IteratorUtils.toList(payload)]` after salesforce query connector to convert the payload into `ArrayList` type.

Comment: Hi it is not working for me, getting "Execution of the expression "org.apache.commons.collections.IteratorUtils.toList(payload)" failed. (org.mule.api.expression.ExpressionRuntimeException) Root Exception stack trace:
[UnexpectedErrorFault [ApiFault  exceptionCode='INVALID_OPERATION_WITH_EXPIRED_PASSWORD'
 exceptionMessage='The users password has expired, you must call SetPassword before attempting any other API operations'
 extendedErrorDetails='{[0]}'
]
]